# How to add F# syntax highlight in blog

Tags: f#

I use blogger and I install a windows live writer, I don't know how to insert F# code.

I installed several code highlighter, none of which support ocaml or f#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I now use [VSPaste](http://www.11011.net/software/vspaste), a plugin for WLW, which can 'paste from Visual Studio' and copies the VS colors.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I followed you link, installed it, and it works great!

Comment: Just FYI, nowadays I think I don't use a plugin; the VS 'Pro Power Tools' have a Copy-As-HTML option that pastes into WLW ok now.

Comment: To follow up on @Brian's comment: Power Tools can be found here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Answer (score 2):

Get a better syntax highlighter. Alternatively, store your code in [Github Gists](http://gist.github.com/) and embed on your blog. That way, any code that Github can highlight, you can highlight.

[BTW, the tool you use to write your blog has nothing to do with your syntax highlighting woes.]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to post this question on [HubFS](http://cs.hubfs.net).  There's more likely to be people there who know what options are available.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how sophisticated syntax highlighting you need. However, most of the formatters should be customizable, so you should be able to adapt them to work reasonably well with F#. On my blog, I use [this formatter](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/) for C# (which is based on regular expressions), and I added my definition for the F# langauge.

Since I typically use the `// comment` format in blog posts and strings are formatted in the same way as in C#, I didn't have to do many changes. I only added a couple of F# operators (mostly as I needed them). I also added F# keywords which you can find in the [language specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf).

Comment: Hi Tomas, how do you get the signature hint for the identifiers as your post here? http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/markdown.html

Answer (score 1):

Since F# is somehow based on ML -- Ocaml or ML highlighter can help in most cases (except for example "//" comments).